# Why do household appliances use DC motors?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, appliances

Couldn’t appliances like fans also use AC motors? What is the advantage of converting to DC?

Comment: How do you know that they don't use AC motors? Most fans that I have seen do in fact use AC motors.

Comment: Universal motor?

Comment: Most appliances do use AC motors. This question assumes a false premise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When they do it's because they are controlled by electronic devices. It's easier to control DC than AC. The conversion also produce a lower DC voltage used by the electronic and safer for the user.

Answer (score 3):

Most household fans do not use DC motors but use AC motors to avoid conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Several types of motors show up in appliances.

- induction motors (washers, dryers, pumps - large, fixed-speed motors)
- universal motors (mixers, blenders, vacuums - small motors)
- shaded-pole motors (fans and blowers)
- brushless DC (some fans and large appliances with variable speed)

Which appliances do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say there is a pretty even mix of AC and DC motors around us, and we have a great understanding of how to control both. Each motor has it's pros and cons and is suited for different applications. A washer or drying machine will use a powerful 3 phase AC motor to move the drums, while a vacuum clear could use both depending on if it's cordless or not. DC motors are becoming more common as motor IC’s have become less expensive and the control and reliability you get from a brushless DC motor are hard to beat. While more and more devices may choose to use brushless DC motors in the future many appliances are bridging that gap with trapezoidal and pure sine wave control that is considered a mixed motor by intelligently manipulating the digital circuitry waveforms and only cost a few extra dollars. Older DC motors used brushes and an H-bridge to operate and had shorter lifespans than their AC counterparts because of frictional wear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all questions like that is usually to reduce manufacturing cost. The combination of a voltage converter and a DC motor has become less costly for the manufacturer than the equivalent AC motor for some products. It may also be less expensive to meet electrical safety standards with that design. Manufacturers never incur more cost to assure more safety than standards require. They also never anything because it is "easier" unless "easier" means less costly to manufacture.